# How to customize the Connection tab in the Data Link Properties dialog?

Tags: c++, user-interface, com, oledb, atl

I am working on an OLEDB Provider that for now leverages the "default" connection dialog provided by `IDBPromptInitialize::PromptDataSource()` which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrdbM.png). The same UI appears when I use my provider with certain client tools like MS Excel or a .udl-file. I am now planning to create my own UI.

When choosing different OLEDB Providers in the Provider tab, I noticed that for some of them the Connection tab looks quite different, e.g. [SQL Server Native Client 11.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax5pF.png).

So customizing it seems to be technically possible. My question is: how?

NOTE: I am aware that I can put together my own UI and that I can pop it up whenever I want. But that won't be magically integrated into that Connection tab of the Data Link Properties dialog, will it?

Thanks!

---

### Edit

Apparently, I was to fast with accepting the answer. I performed all steps as described. When I use my provider in my own test application that creates a property sheet, everything works [beautifully][3]. My test app calls `ISpecifyPropertyPages::GetPages` on my provider and passes the result to `OleCreatePropertyFrame` as described in the answer.

However, when I use it with the Data Link dialog, as soon as I select my provider and klick the Next button or one of the tabs, the tabs just disappear. Only the Provider tab stays.
Debugging it I can see that `GetPages` is successfully called, but then only my ConnectionTab's constructor is called (without any error) and right after that the tabs disappear (no crash!). No `IPropertyPage` method nor anything else was invoked.
Any Idea what could be the issue?

---

### Edit - Solved

Ok, I've got it. In my AdvancedTab class I was missing the `COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IPersistPropertyBag)` in the COM Map. I was focussing too much on the Connection tab as I wanted to have that working first.

If anyone is interested:
Putting `#define _ATL_DEBUG_QI` before `#include <atlcom.h>` made me discover that the `QueryInterface` call failed for `IPersistPropertyBag`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is described here: [Interfaces Implemented by the Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722642.aspx)

The OLEDB provider's object that implements `IIDBInitialize`/`IDBProperties` must also implement `IServiceProvider`.

The system will call this `IServiceProvider` implementation with `OLEDB_SVC_DSLPropertyPages` (from MSDAGUID.H) as the service guid and [ISpecifyPropertyPages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695217.aspx) as the interface ID.

> ISpecifyPropertyPages::GetPages Fills a counted
>   array of GUID values, where each GUID specifies the CLSID of each
>   property page that can be displayed in the property sheet for this
>   object. GetPages is called by the Data Link core component to get an
>   array of exactly two CLSIDs that represent the extensible property
>   pages: the first to replace the **Connection** tab, and the second to
>   replace the **Advanced** tab. These pages must be registered properly so
>   that they can be cocreated by the Data Link core component in-process.

These property pages are standard Windows [property pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686577.aspx).

Comment: I'm having issues implementing this. It works fine when I write my own property sheet application, but it doesn't work with the Data Link dialog. See updated question.

Comment: @yira - sounds like a bug in your code. can't help w/o reproducing code.

Comment: your were right! It was a stupid bug... missing an interface entry. Thank you!